# Optimal DB Schema

Tags: mysql, database-design, orm, schema, laravel

I'm about to redesign a DB schema and I'm considering using an ORM in my app, would the below schema work with, for example, Eloquent ORM, or would I also have to add the JOIN tables as well?

```
ISSUES(ID, ORGANIZATION_ID, DATE, TIME, CATEGORY_ID, TYPE_ID, ISSUE_DETAILS_ID)
ISSUE_DETAILS(ID, NAME, STATUS, EMAIL)
ORGANIZATIONS(ID, NAME, ADDRESS, CONTACT)
CATEGORIES(ID, CATEGORY)
TYPES(ID, TYPE, CATEGORY_ID)
```

Comment: Looks clean and nicely organised. When you map the ORM, you can map your entities so you can do something like `Issue.Organization.Name` and then the ORM will translate that to a join for you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I'd probably do differently is have the `issue_id` foreign key on the `issue_details` table so that you could have a **one to one** relationship.

So if you were using Eloquent you could do something like this.

```
echo $issue->details->name;
```

I'm not entirely sure what you'll be storing in the details table though, perhaps there will be multiple details for an issue in which case you'd have a **many to many** relationship.

Comment: I suppose I can combine issues and issue_details, i was concerned about having a "fat" table. Do I gain or lose anything by keeping it separate/combined?

Comment: You don't have to combine them if you don't want to. It depends what you need. There isn't really much to be worried about with it. If for all the requests you need the details it might be easier to just have it all in the one table so you don't have to join or fetch the other details every time. But then again you might only need the details in a few places, in which case it might make more sense to have a separate table.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Jason suggested, you could also remove the `category_id` from the `issues` table since each `type` already has a `category`, you already have access to the category through the type.

i.e. `$issue->type->category`